# Socket.io stops working on handshake after 100+ users

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I have a site which, when less than ~100 people are on it, works fine. But after that point, I often get an error saying:

```
WebSocket connection to ' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
```

Followed by a bunch of Post errors

```
GET <my server> 400 (Bad Request)
```

If I refresh the site a couple times, it works. I am so lost as to why this is happening. Any suggestions?

Here's my code in brief:

```
//server side
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8081);


var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(8081);

//client side

var origin = window.location.origin;
console.log("origin is: " + origin);
var socket = io.connect(origin);
```

I'm using Express and decided to use socket.io to talk between the app.js(server) and index.html (client). Literally all I'm doing is updating a hashtable on client side. Are there any other alternatives to using socket.io to talk between client and server?

Comment: What is the URL for which the 400 response is returned? Are you using a reverse proxy in front of Node?

Comment: @robertklep https://roshiclips.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LkZky02&sid=HepQf6zL7ygdaWXoAAA6. And no...not sure what that is?

Comment: It looks like you're using NGINX in front of Node, so NGINX is the reverse proxy. When you get a 400 error, look at the exact response that the server is sending back (in your browser's dev console). For instance, I'm getting a 400 on the URL that you're posting because of _"Session ID unknown"_, which is an internal error thrown by `engine.io` (the transport layer of `socket.io`) when a connection is made on behalf of a client that the server knows nothing about. I think there's something in your server causing this.

Comment: @robertklep if you go to my homepage: https://roshiclips.com/watch?v=ntTMReWFVj and go to console log, you'll see that the socket connection fails on websocket, but works fine on polling. Should I just force polling?

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of your NGINX configuration, specifically the parts that relate to proxying the requests to your Node.js server. I wonder if NGINX isn't configured to pass WebSocket connections.

Comment: @robertklep thank you so much man for all your help by the way. i tried accessing the nginx folder and it's not even there? I tried seeing /etc/nginx/ but the nginx folder isn't there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142587/discussion-between-chris-jones-and-robertklep).